# In C, what is an unconditional jump?

Tags: c, terminology

I have to fill out some documentation regarding a C project i worked on. One topic is whether I used "unconditional jumps".

As far as I know, a "break" statement counts as a jump. And I have a few of those that fire when a condition in a loop is met. Does that make it a "conditional jump"?

Another example is when there are standard "break" statements in a switch case, are those conditional or unconditional?

Basically, what constitutes an "unconditional jump" in C?

Comment: When you look at the Linux kernel source, you find a lot of `goto out;` in functions, sometimes also to different label like out1, out2 etc. See also http://blog.regehr.org/archives/894

Comment: Did you ask whomever asked you to fill out the documentation? Can you track it back it its author & request clarification. Perhaps the document itself could be updated? "did you use any unconditional jumps (i.e goto or break)?"

Comment: Related: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/409878/conditional-jump-statements-in-middle-and-high-level-languages

Answer (score 4):

It is a matter of terminology.

IMHO, any `break`, `continue`, `goto`, `return` which is not in the body of an `if` or `else` or `case` is an inconditional jump.

So obviously

```
if (foobar) goto somelabel;
```

is a conditional jump.

In

```
if (foobar) {
   x = something();
   y = other(x);
   return;
}
```

I would believe that the `return` is conditional. Some people might object that because of the previous statements it is not (and only the entire block is conditional)

BTW, I heard of "[unconditional jump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_%28computer_science%29)" more when speaking of machine code than everything else.

Read also about [basic blocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block)

I believe that your bureaucracy is just asking you if you used `goto`; you could ask your management or client about what is really meant. I feel sorry for you that you have to lose your time on such (IMHO stupid or useless) questions.

Comment: Our train of thought is similar. And my documentation DOES originate from a machine code background. I guess it is a rather gray area when it comes to C.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional means it may not be followed depending on some condition. Unconditional means that is program flow reaches that point it always will continue at the target.

A `if` and a `switch` are a conditional jumps.

At the end of the `then` clause of an `if` is an unconditional jump to after the `else` clause. `break`s in a switch are also unconditional.

Comment: How is there an unconditional jump after the then clause? Wouldn't we ALWAYS jump to the else clause then? If not, how is it UNconditional?

Comment: @Solver after you finish the `then` clause you need to skip the `else` (by definition of the clauses), that requires a unconditional jump

Comment: @ratchet_freak Why would you jump to "else" if the first "then" was true? Something I am missing?

Comment: @Solver you jump to *after* the else, in other words to the code outside the if-else

Comment: A `break` in a `case` label is obviously conditional, as it depends on the switch condition being hit in the first place. All jumps are unconditional once you've passed the test condition. Therefore you must always have the right scope in mind, and the right scope for `break` is exactly the full switch statement (you don't break to the next case label or back to the caller of the function).

Comment: @MSalters no once you reach the break you **always** jump to after the switch/loop it is enclosed in. That is the definition of unconditional jump.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: That's why I say that all jumps are unconditional once you pass the condition to reach them. But trivially, `if(boolCondition) { case true: break; case false: break; }` means that one of the two `break` statement will NOT be executed. Obviously they can't be both unconditional by your definition.

Comment: @MSalters I am glad that I am not alone in this dubiousness. Basically, almost any jump can be seen as conditional or unconditional by modifying the scope. That was what actually what made me post the question in the first place. It's becoming more and more obvious that the documentation is incomplete and/or faulty.

Comment: @MSalters narrow the scope to *just the instruction*