# Conditional jump statements in middle- and high-level languages

Tags: programming-languages, terminology, conditions

In Java, C, and C++ we have the following jump statements: `break`, `continue`, `goto`, and `return`. In C#, there is also `throw`.

I'm not really familiar with either of these languages. This is simply what I have read on the web.

All these jump statements are unconditional. I tried to find mention about **conditional** jump statements, but all links lead to Assembly.

**Is it correct to say that conditional jump statements exist in Assembly only?**

Some people on the Internet are telling me that `if` is actually a conditional jump statement, but I don't think so. At least, it's not described as such in [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/jump-statements-cpp) or [QT](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Coding_Style#Jump_statements_.28break.2C_continue.2C_return.2C_and_goto.29) documentation.

Regarding comments to this question:

> How are `if` or `switch ... case` are not conditional jump statements? Why do you think these aren't? – πάντα ῥεῖ

@πάνταῥεῖ - As I see it, `if`, `switch`, `return`, `break` etc. are **control flow statements**. Jump statements are a **subset** of them. And please note that neither Microsoft, nor QT, nor any another documentation treat `if` as a jump statement.

The difference between control flow statements and jump statements, as I see it, is described here: https://www.inf.unibz.it/~calvanese/teaching/06-07-ip/lecture-notes/uni06/node45.html

Comment: How are `if` or `switch ... case` are not conditional jump statements? Why do you think these aren't?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ As I see it, `if`, `switch`, `return`, `break` etc. are **conditional jump statements**. Jump statements is a **subset** of conditional jump statements. And please note that neither Microsoft, nor QT, nor any another documentation treat `if` as a jump statement.

Comment: Well, you could add some details to your question (e.g. what your definition of a _jump statement_ is) to improve it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Done.

Comment: That's not a definition.

Comment: Ooops, I mean `if`, `switch`, `return`, `break` are control flow statements. Jump statements are a subset of control flow ones. Mistyped in a hurry.

Comment: And what's the difference of _control flow_ vs _jump statements_?

Comment: Better cite that source directly in your question also (instead of just linking to it).

Comment: Also: Java and C++ also have throw, and Java doesn't have goto.

Comment: As I understand, `try`, `catch`, `finally`, and `throw` should be called "exception handling statements". https://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction which the linked source makes is unclear.

In my view, the distinction it is making is between *structured* flow control statements, and *unstructured* flow control statements.

A "conditional jump" is simply an `if` statement and the like. `if` is also a structured statement. Most structured languages don't expose an unstructured conditional jump statement (although it exists at the assembly level).

An "unconditional jump" is a `goto` statement and the like. `goto` is also considered an unstructured statement, although in structured languages nowadays there are often constraints on exactly what it can do. An example of a "structured unconditional jump", is a function call - the function will always be jumped into (which is what makes it unconditional), but it must also jump back (which is what makes it structured).

`break` and `continue` are often regarded as the last vestiges of unstructured flow control, although they are by definition local to a structured flow control statement.

The distinctions between "conditional" and "structured" flow control statements are wholly orthogonal.

I will add as well, a sensible definition of a "flow control statement" is one which is capable of causing code to be executed *other than* that on the very next line. A conditional jump is one which jumps away from the next line in some cases. An unconditional jump is one which jumps away from the next line in all cases.

Comment: Break and continue are structured. They don’t let you jump just anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Steve. You know, some Basic-like languages have GoSub flow control statement. It's very similar to GoTo with the only difference that when the subroutine is done, the execution will resume right after the statement. That is, it works as a hybrid of GoTo and a function call. Do you think it is correct to say that GoSub is unstructured statement?

Comment: @candied_orange, that's what I say, `goto` is constrained in structured languages.

Comment: @john-c-j,`gosub` is antiquated, and I've never seen a real piece of code that uses it. It is unstructured in the sense it jumps into the middle of a method, notwithstanding (iirc) that it returns to the call site. I would treat it as an unstructured statement, although some of these arguments raged 40 years ago. Arguably (I write in a state of inebriation), structured code corresponds with indentation, with decisions being at the same level of indentation. If you can jump into the middle of a block, it's unstructured.

Comment: @johnc.j. Gosub would be structured so long as you must return to the call point. It’s how you call a subroutine. The modern form of that is calling a void “function”.

Comment: Thangs again, Steve and candied_orange. I see that it's somewhat debatable. And back to the original question. It seems that for the sake of creating more user-friendly, less cumbersome terminology, most of companies (and developers / technical writers hired by them) use the following "short" names: instead of "uncondtional jump statement" they say "jump statement", and instead of "condtional jump statement" they say "branching statement" (or "selection statement" or "decision-making statement"). Right?

Comment: Some examples: [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html), [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/statements-cpp), and there are a lot more.

Comment: @john-c-j, I'd broadly agree with that. I'd suggest that the word "jump" has acquired the implication of being both unstructured and unconditional. Because, as I say, modern languages only expose conditional jumps as structured statements, these structured statements *are not jumps* by that definition (because a jump is something that defies the tenets of structured programming), and it is not then necessary to emphasise the unconditionality of the remaining unconditional jumps either, because they are the only kind.

Comment: Obviously though, if you go down to the assembly level, structured statements cease to exist, and the conditional jump is an elementary instruction, so the word "jump" can no longer carry the baggage it does for those who spend all their time in structured languages.

Comment: _"jump has acquired the implication of being both unstructured and unconditional. Because, as I say, modern languages only expose conditional jumps as structured statements"_ - Hmm. The links I posted earlier ([Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/jump-statements-cpp) and [QT](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Coding_Style#Jump_statements_.28break.2C_continue.2C_return.2C_and_goto.29), and I believe there are a lot more) says that jump statements are `break`, `continue`, `return`, and `goto`.

Comment: But you said that `break` and `continue` are structured (and by the same logic `return` is). That is, the statement "_jump has acquired the implication of being both unstructured and unconditional_" doesn't look really correct. I mean, according to existing documentation.

Comment: @john-c-j, no I said that break and continue are *unstructured* jumps, albeit that they occur within structured blocks. So also is return an unstructured jump, when it occurs elsewhere than at the end of the method. Structured statements are (I hazard the following definition offhand...) those in which there is a block with one entry, one exit, execution progresses linearly from entry to exit, and in which any conditions for entry or exit (including iterations which move from exit back to entry, or decisions which determine entry into subsidiary blocks) are stated *at the start of the block*.

Comment: It can then be seen immediately that a continue (except at the exit - that is, the last line - of a loop), a break (except at the exit of a block), or a return (except at the exit of a method) are unstructured jumps, because the condition under which the block is exited, cannot have been stated at the entry point (unless these jumps are unconditional and occur prior to unreachable code, so that they are in effect the exit points of the block).

Comment: As I also said earlier, these arguments raged with previous generations, and there are grey areas, particularly over the single exit principle. Most languages preserve some unstructured elements, where the jump is confined to the entry or exit point of the structured block which contains the jump, because they are regarded as convenient for some cases, and as safe enough in code that is otherwise well-structured. Goto, however, is still shunned, because it is capable not only of prematurely exiting blocks, but also jumping into them and across them.

Comment: If I were to speculate why jumping in is considered worse than premature exit, it is because you can potentially jump in from anywhere, whereas you can only prematurely exit the block from within, so there is more locality with premature exits that with in-jumps. Moreover, the conditions for entry and exit are usually stated at the start of the block, and most methods have some sort of checking or parameter verification step at their entry. That is, there tends to be (in one way or another) a lot more action at the beginning of blocks which is crucial for operation or for reasoning about them.

Comment: Excellent explanations. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It’s trivial in most languages to compose a conditional jump from  existing features, for example

```
If (x > 0) goto y;
```

So there is very little demand for a conditional jump statement, and therefore you don’t see it. Having a statement like

```
Ifgoto (x > 0, y);
```

Would seem unnecessary, confusing, and stupid.

Comment: I think the crux is that in structured languages, the `if` and the `goto` are considered two separate statements, consisting of an unconditional jump within a conditional block (rather than an conditional jump). But in C's terse syntax, this pair of statements is scarcely any longer than the shortest conceivable single statement which expresses a conditional jump. It is not immediately apparent why a `goto y if x;` is confusing or stupid, but it is certainly unnecessary in C given that it is no shorter or structurally simpler than the shortest two-statement alternative `if (x) goto y;`